# Javascript - Play audio clip every 30 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, audio, playback

I have a webpage that plays a short audio clip the moment the page loads.

It uses an audio player called nifty player.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="0" height="0" id="niftyPlayer1" align="">
<param name=movie value="niftyplayer.swf?file=audio.mp3&as=1">
<param name=quality value=high>
<param name=bgcolor value=#FFFFFF>
<embed src="niftyplayer.swf?file=audio.mp3&as=1" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF width="0" height="0" name="niftyPlayer1" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
</object>
```

I would like this audio to replay every 30 seconds for 4 times. The time spacing and frequency will change.

How can this be done? I think I could reload the `object` every 30 seconds, but I don't know if this would work or how to do it. I cant seem to find an audio player that suits my needs, my lack of javascript skills is showing.

Comment: That won't get annoying ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose you should use HTML5 **audio** control.
You Can customize it as much as you want.